# Linq to sql left join additional null check needed

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Query below is working as it's expected but just one feature is missing. DepartmentId field is nullable and when iterating users I just want to get the users which do not have departmentId

```
from document in _documentRepository.GetAll()
from documentShare in document.DocumentShares where documentShare.UserId == input.SharedUserId 

join sU in _userRepository.GetAll() 
on documentShare.UserId /* Additional null check should be here 
like documentShare.DepartmentId == null */  equals sU.Id into sharedUsersInfo
```

As far as I know I should make a group join but even I tried I could not get the result I wanted. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `DepartmentId` property of `User` or `DocumentShare`?

Comment: @IvanStoev DepartmentId is a property of DocumentShare, I have also departments joining later in this query and then I will need userId of DocumentShare table to become null aswell. I thought if i can take care of departmentId first then I could do the same for userId aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check for not null values.
hope this helps :)
**documentShare.DepartmentId.HasValue && documentShare.DepartmentId.Value**

Comment: Your answer does not fit in my sutiation. Where will I tell this "on documentShare.UserId /* Additional null check should be here 
like documentShare.DepartmentId == null */  equals sU.Id into sharedUsersInfo" here exactly???

Comment: hello, you can check both conditions ,"where  documentShare.UserId.HasValue && documentShare.UserId.Value(if userId can take null values) && !documentShare.DepartmentId.HasValue (to check for the null values)".Hope this works you in checking both the conditions.

Comment: mate I cannot specify this condition inside join line cause i do not select anything right away, the query goes on so your answer is nothing to do with my case.  maybe my approach is wrong I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here if you could try it (sorry can't comment yet):

...
join sU in _userRepository.GetAll() 
on documentShare.UserId equals sU.Id 
`and documentShare.DepartmentId == null`
into sharedUsersInfo

Comment: unfortunately there's no term as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply add the additional constraint to the "where" clause of the documentShares?

```
...
from documentShare in document.DocumentShares where documentShare.UserId == input.SharedUserId 
     && documentShare.DepartmentId == null
...
```

Comment: in this case I cannot specify my condition exactly because I need departmentId to be null when I call users and I want userId to be null when I call departments. my query goes on like this and both of the values can be null in my scenario.